# How to do Xamarin.uwp in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, xamarin.uwp, xamarin.winphone

I downloaded latest visual studio 2017 and I have chosen Xamarin while installing it and I already have visual studio 2015 with Xamarin and I was able to develop visual studio Xamarin.winphone along with Xamarin.ios and Xamarin.Droid.

I am aware winphone is deprecated in visual studio 2017 and I thought to develop Xamarin.uwp by migrating all my winphone code uwp.

But When I create a new Xamarin native project I am not able to find Xamarin.uwp but I can find Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Droid.

Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4trjE.png)

What could have gone wrong ?

Comment: Please show more detail about your Windows 10 SDK version. You could find it in the Visual Studio installer.

Comment: Where can I find can you give me the steps please ?

Comment: Please enter the “Visual Studio Installer” in the conrtana search box.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks it worked ... But As I didn't have Windows 10 I couldn't create UWP apps though .. You can answer the post I will accept it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have installed Windows 10 SDK. The following is check steps.

1. Enter the “Visual Studio Installer” in the conrtana search box.
   [image]
2. Click the modify button in the window of Visual Studio Installer.
   [image]
3. Select the version you need to install.